# Django REST Framework ModelSerializer read_only_fields not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following `ListCreateAPIView`

```
  class TodoAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Todo.objects.filter(user=user)
```

And in my `serializers.py`, I have

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description',
                  'completed', 'created_at')
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
```

But the problem is when I POST data into the form, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /todo/
NOT NULL constraint failed: todo_todo.user_id
```

**models.py**

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Can you add Todo model?

Comment: Can you print out the Request.POST and show what you get here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `id` field, but with `user` field. This field is not nullable in DB and since is required. You can just pass current user as defalt, for this use [`CurrentUserDefault`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description',
                  'completed', 'created_at', 'user')
```

Comment: Tried your edited answer, now it works. Thank you :)